# HTML tangled headings display

Tags: html

I have a single responsive html webpage. The header background image takes a quick second to load in the browser. Before the image loads, the html markup loads first in a tangled fashion. 
The html markup headings and ul first display overlapping. When the background image completes loading the headings and ul stretch to their final position.

Is there a way to avoid this odd html markup display?

Assigning a header height: auto did not solve the problem.

Comment: Set a size on the header equal to the size of the image. The movement likely happens because the header element is small when the page first loads, and then becomes much larger when it is filled by the image. Alternately, position the other elements in such a way that they always appear in the right place, regardless of the other elements (be aware, however, that fixed positions are often brittle).

Comment: Correct that works!The responsive image resizes according to the viewport size. Is there a way for the header to adopt the viewport height before the image loads?

Comment: If you have breakpoints set, you can set your header width inside the breakpoint. For example, on the "large" breakpoint, the header may be 768px wide, but on the "small" breakpoint, you could set it to be 250px.